# The incompatibility between Euler and Alegreya

Tags: fonts

I'm working on a complex document in which I would like to use Alegreya font (for regular text) and AMS Euler font (for typesetting maths) with PDFLaTeX, and have recently noticed that the `\dot` command does not work as expected. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage{euler}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\selectlanguage{polish}

\begin{document}
A bad looking derivative: $\dot{\gamma}$.
\end{document}
```

However, if I import only one of these packages (I mean, euler or Alegreya), then everything is fine. It seems therefore that these two aren't compatible and are the source of my problem (the dot should be placed lower). How to solve it?

[EDIT]: I've attached the pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What's wrong with the `\dot`?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your output?

Comment: I have uploaded a picture showing two outputs, the second one without loaded euler package.

Comment: I don't get that output, but the correct one. See http://i.imgur.com/uqp2qxn.png. Have you tried updating your TeX distribution?

Comment: The `euler` package should be considered obsolete and `eulervm` used instead. But I don't get so high a dot even with `euler`.

Comment: The versions of packages that I'm using are: `eulervm.sty 2005/01/11 v4.0` and `Alegreya.sty 2014/01/16 (Bob Tennent)`. How can I check how obsolete they are?

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not reproducible with current packages. The OP should update his TeX distribution and check the output again.